# Curl redirect link cut after "*.pdf"

Tags: curl

I have a Problem with curl and for the moment I can give you just examples of the links. I hope you can help me with this.
I have a URL "https://www.myexample/documents/15611"
This link will be redirected to somthing like "https://myexample/*/*.pdf?*sometrashwithmanymanychars".

Not working

```
curl -L -O https://www.myexample/documents/15611
```

not working either:

```
curl -L -O https://myexample/*/*.pdf?*sometrashwithmanymanychars
```

This is working

```
curl -L -O https://myexample/*/*.pdf
```

So my idea was:
Do

```
curl -L -O https://www.myexample/documents/15611
```

But cut the redirected link after ".PDF?"

Is something like this possible?
Zio